# PDO Exception error on index

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129

I get the following error on my local machine. (Mac OSX running Apache/MySQL natively) I can run Magento from the frontend, but I can't reindex at the command.

Comment: Just a comment, this part of Alan's fix worked You might also have some luck changing the server to 127.0.0.1 from localhost. (When the system sees an IP address, it knows not to connect via the socket file, but instead to connect via TCP)

Comment: This comment may be help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331463/93583

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a guess, but it sounds like

1. Your command line php executable uses a different `php.ini` file than the web server
2. The `php.ini` file your command line version uses has a different, and invalid, value set for the [mysql.default_socket](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php) ini setting

When you specify a MySQL server host as `localhost`, you're telling the system to use this socket file to connect to the database server.  Check the value when using your local web-server, and make sure that same value is set for the command line program's `ini` file.

You might also have some luck changing the server to `127.0.0.1` from `localhost`. (When the system sees an IP address, it knows **not** to connect via the socket file, but instead to connect via TCP)

Comment: The change to `127.0.0.1` fixed this issue in MAMP where re-indexing would fail from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions to change the socket on a server:

http://pravams.com/2011/05/26/magento-pdo-exception/

---

And if you get the problem with MAMP/XAMPP, open a terminal to create  symbolic link (that was my solution, tested on MAC OS X) :

**MAMP:**

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
cd /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**XAMPP:**

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
cd /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was in settings of Mamp. 
Run Apache/MySQL server as www instead of as user. 
Once I changed that I was able to run shell scripts in shell/ directory without any errors