# Add database getting error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: magento2, database, installation, docker, linux

I tried to install Magento using XAMPP for Linux (I use 32-bit Ubuntu), I've created a database, and when you want to add via Magento Installer I get an error message like this:

[image: Picture]

I've tried a variety of ways, but it does not work, is there a solution?

Comment: Make sure ur Host is correct

Comment: @AnkitShah When I try to change the host `febri` , I get the following error like `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Comment: @FebriyantoNugroho replace localhost to 127.0.0.1 and then check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO Exception error on index](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/pdo-exception-error-on-index)

Comment: @ManthanDave Error result I have `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: @FebriyantoNugroho yes thats correct, now enter your database username password (may be its - root) because default is "root". enter "root" in password and check.

Comment: @ManthanDave Before I install this XAMPP, MySQL does not ask for a password when performing the installation, you should be using a password?

Comment: @FebriyantoNugroho by default password is "root" so you must need to pass database password while installing magento2 . if you want to check open your phpmyadmin(database) goto useraccounts and check

Comment: @ManthanDave Sir, after adding `root` password, error result I have `Database user does not have enough privileges. Please make sure SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER privileges are granted to table 'magento'.`

Comment: Yes thats because your root user dont have all privileges ..go to your database  and give all privileges to root  user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace **localhost to 127.0.0.1** and check

This is commonly caused by a different instance of PHP being used by the PHP command line compared to the web server. In particular, **mysql.sock** might be misconfigured.

Refer this magento devdocs link  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

You can also refer - [PDO Exception error on index](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/pdo-exception-error-on-index)

It will works

Comment: Do I have to add value to the `pdo_mysql.default_socket` ?

Comment: @FebriyantoNugroho after chaning localhost to 127.0.0.1  now you have access denied error right ? please confirm ?

Comment: Yes sir, of course

Comment: @FebriyantoNugroho so now your first issue is solved , you just need to pass correct password . Check your database password with privillages and enter that password in the password field. it will works

Comment: I'll try it later

Comment: Another dead link that could have helped me. Thanks Adobe!

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run below command and look for **MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT_33060_TCP_ADDR**. You can use for your database server host.

```
php -i
```

[image]